# App missing in app list but working if launched

Tags: vlc, 16.10

Ubuntu 16.10 x64

I Installed VLC through sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install vlc.

VlC is present in the search bar and working OK (If I open it and use open file it can play the videos), but it's not present in the application list when I right-click a video to open with a different app other than default, and it's also absent in the System>Details> Default applications menu...
I unistalled it and re-installed and I got the same problem.

Looks like some kind of bug rather than my fault...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5MBT.jpg

in the images I couldn't take a screenshot with the drop-down menu displayed, but for example in the last picture (details) it only has "video" option (the default player).

Answer (score 0):

kind of "solved" it... I opened the Ubuntu Software center and it showed VLC as not installed, I then tried sudo dpkg --configure -a and sudo apt-get -f install from terminal but they did not solve the issue...

I then installed VLC from Ubuntu software center WITHOUT unistalling it beforehand... and now VLC is correctly listed.

But now I have it doubled in the dash... I tried sudo apt-get remove vlc and it looks like it removed the "wrong" VLC, because if I click it it won't start (although it's still present in the dash).
How can I delete its "pointer"? Is there a way to tell apart the two and maybe delete the folder of the bad package?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu4dA.jpg

on the left "VLC media player" is the one installed through apt-get, the bad one... on the right "Lettore multimediale VLC" is the one installed though software center, the working one.